# How can I import a local python file? it's currently giving an import cannot be resolved pylance error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror, pylance

```
from dinocore import Object, grabScreen
```

dinocore is the name of my other local Python file, it's in the same folder. So far I've tried moving the files around into different folders, but that hasn't worked with many different combinations. It says the error is

> Import "dinocore" could not be resolved

I've also tried specifying the path like this:

```
from botscript.dinocore import Object, grabScreen
```

I've also tried tracing back further than that in the import path.

Comment: I'm not sure what your file layout looks like, but you might try using a relative import.  Try `from .dinocore import Object, grabScreen`. (notice that I added a '.' to the front of the module name)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cryptofool, I tried that and still not recognizing the "dinocore" py file.

Comment: the file pathing is oia.py (The root) then botscript.py (the folder housing both bot.py and dinocore) I hope that makes sense, couldn't get stack overflow to save the spacing I made, so it goes Oia.py\botscript.py\both bot.py and dinocore.py

Comment: Sharing the directory structure and name of current file would be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

I use the subfolder modules to store my .py files that I use in main.py script in the application root directory and import my modules scripts into main.py using **from subfolderName import myScriptName**:

```py
'''
AppFolder:    
    main.py   

    modules:
        myTools.py
'''
from modules import myTools as mt
```

Comment: Wow, I think this solved my issue, thank you so much! It was really that simple all along